# Collect order total inside shipping method

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shipping-methods

I created my own shipping method but I want the price to be set as 10% of the subTotal.

I think I should use something of the session or the quote cart inside the collectRates function of Magento but I can't seem to figure it out.

Can you help me out?

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
    $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
    $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

    $method->setCarrier('percentagetotaal');
    $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

    $method->setMethod('percentagetotaal');
    $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

    $percentage = 10;
    // I want to get the session and get the cart subtotal and calculate 10% of the $subTotal.
    // How to get $subTotal;
    $price = ($subTotal * $percentage) / 100; //calculate 10% of the product cost



    $method->setPrice($price);
    $method->setCost($price);

    $result->append($method);

    return $result;
}
```

So I want to know how to get $subTotal inside the collectRates function.

Answer (score 3):

In this you can get Quote id from $request object.

Lets do some trick in this case:

First inject  Quote Factory class  **`\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory`**  at **`__construct()`**

Then From *get **load quote factory** by `quote id` which you will get from `$items = $request->getAllItems();`*

then easily you can get subtotal

---

```
protected $quoteFactory;
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
    ) {
     $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
   }
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    $items = $request->getAllItems();
    $quoteId = false;

     foreach ($items  as $item) 
     {
         $quoteId = $item->getQuoteId();
         break;
     }

     $quote = $this->getCurrentQuote($quoteId);

    /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
    $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
    $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

    $method->setCarrier('percentagetotaal');
    $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

    $method->setMethod('percentagetotaal');
    $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

    $percentage = 10;
    // I want to get the session and get the cart subtotal and calculate 10% of the $subTotal.
    // How to get $subTotal;
     $totals = $quote->getTotals();
    $price = ( $totals['subtotal']->getValue() * $percentage) / 100; //calculate 10% of the product cost



    $method->setPrice($price);
    $method->setCost($price);

    $result->append($method);

    return $result;
}

 protected function getCurrentQuote($quoteId){

 return $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get subtotal, you should use `$request->getPackageValueWithDiscount()`.

Your code then would be:

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
    $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();


    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
    $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

    $subTotal = $request->getBaseCurrency()->convert($request->getPackageValueWithDiscount(), $request->getPackageCurrency());
    $subTotal = $request->getPackageValueWithDiscount();
    // Additional line if some is dealing with free shipping (not this case).
    /* $this->_updateFreeMethodQuote($request); */

    $method->setCarrier('percentagetotaal');
    $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

    $method->setMethod('percentagetotaal');
    $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

    $percentage = 10;
    $price = ($subTotal * $percentage) / 100; //calculate 10% of total cost

    $method->setPrice($price);
    $method->setCost($price);

    $result->append($method);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: There is also a free module https://owebia.com/doc/en/magento2-module-advanced-shipping#examples_using_formulas